# How to convert object to json in Nim

Tags: json, nim-lang

I'm making a small web service in Nim, and I need to respond to requests with json. I'm using the [jester module](https://github.com/dom96/jester) to make the service. I expect I can use the json module in Nim's base library to construct some kind of object with fields and values, and then convert it to a json string. But how? Or is there a better way to construct json in Nim?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The marshal module includes a generic object-to-json serialisation algorithm that works for any type (currently, it uses run-time type introspection).

```
import marshal

type
  Person = object
    age: int
    name: string

var p = Person(age: 38, name: "Torbjørn")

echo($$p)
```

The output will be:

```
{"age": 38, "name": "Torbj\u00F8rn"}
```

Comment: While Grzegorz answer was just what I was looking for, this answer was also very usefull, interesting, and simpler than using the json module. Cool!

Comment: It seems that in Nim everyone makes operators?

Comment: This is **not** how you should serialise to JSON in Nim. The `marshal` module is Python's equivalent to `pickle`, the fact that it uses JSON as its serialisation format is a pure coincidence, do not use it to serialise objects to JSON. This is especially something you shouldn't do now that the `json` module supports effectively the same thing: https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2uPe

Answer (score 11):

In Nim you use the [json module](http://nim-lang.org/docs/json.html) to create `JsonNode` objects which are [object variants](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut2.html#object-oriented-programming-object-variants). These can be constructed with the individual procs like [newJObject()](http://nim-lang.org/docs/json.html#newJObject) and then populate the `fields` sequence. Another quicker way is to use the [%() proc](http://nim-lang.org/docs/json.html#%,openArray[tuple[string,JsonNode]]) which accepts a sequence of tuples where one value is the string with the json field and the other the individual `JsonNode`.

Here's an example showing both ways:

```
import json

type
  Person = object ## Our generic person record.
    age: int ## The age of the person.
    name: string ## The name of the person.

proc `%`(p: Person): JsonNode =
  ## Quick wrapper around the generic JObject constructor.
  result = %[("age", %p.age), ("name", %p.name)]

proc myCustomJson(p: Person): JsonNode =
  ## Custom method where we replicate manual construction.
  result = newJObject()
  # Initialize empty sequence with expected field tuples.
  var s: seq[tuple[key: string, val: JsonNode]] = @[]
  # Add the integer field tuple to the sequence of values.
  s.add(("age", newJInt(p.age)))
  # Add the string field tuple to the sequence of values.
  s.add(("name", newJString(p.name)))
  result.fields = s

proc test() =
  # Tests making some jsons.
  var p: Person
  p.age = 24
  p.name = "Minah"
  echo(%p) # { "age": 24,  "name": "Minah"}
  p.age = 33
  p.name = "Sojin"
  echo(%p) # { "age": 33,  "name": "Sojin"}
  p.age = 40
  p.name = "Britney"
  echo p.myCustomJson # { "age": 40,  "name": "Britney"}

when isMainModule: test()
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's a terrible way to generate JSON, nobody these days generates it by manually writing serialisation functions

Comment: Please see the discussion at https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/6707 about this incorrect answer.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else finding the `marshal`-based answer in this thread. Use this instead:

```
import json

type
  Person = object
    age: int
    name: string

var p = Person(age: 38, name: "Torbjørn")
echo(%p)
```

Note that you should not be using `marshal` for this purpose, it is the equivalent of the `pickle` module in Python and it may generate JSON that has extra data that you likely don't want. Also, right now it's just a coincidence that it generates JSON, it may choose a different format in the future.

Comment: as a Nim newbie... what is going on here?  in what circumstances does `echo(%p)` "just work" for your data structure, or fail?  presumably if your `Person` type has attributes which aren't `string` or `int` then you will have to do some more work - what would be an idiomatic Nim way to handle that?

Comment: so the `%` in `%p` is this generic proc from `json` module? https://nim-lang.org/docs/json.html#%25%2Cstring Does that mean you could implement your own specialization (is that the right terminology?) of `%` to handle other data types, eg to serialize `DateTime -> string` for example?

Comment: well, I just tried it and exactly that works https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2uPX ...this is nice 

Comment: @Anentropic `echo` implicitly calls `$` on its arguments (see the documentation for `echo`). `$` is Nim's "toString" function. So just implement `$` for your datatype and you can print its string representation. `%` returns a `JsonNode`, and  `$` is implemented for `JsonNode`, so `echo %p` (or `echo $ %p`) works. Pretty straightforward, really. "presumably if your Person type has attributes which aren't string or int then you will have to do some more work " -- sure ... the implementer of the json module did that work. (And `int` isn't special -- `$` for `int` is provided by the Nim library.)

Comment: Ah I didn't notice `$` is involved too. The json module provides implementations of `%` covering the basic types which easily translate to json (numbers, strings, sequences, hash-tables and objects), for any other types you have to provide your own implementation (as we'd expect) otherwise you get a compile error when you `echo(%p)`.

Comment: @Anentropic "otherwise you get a compile error when you echo(%p)" -- you get a compilation error when you refer to `%p`, period ... `echo` has nothing to do with it.  `echo %p` is effectively `stdout.writeln $(%p)`. If there's no `%` in scope defined to take an argument of `p` 's type, then of course that's an error. Again, this is all quite straightforward, and isn't speciflc to `json`, `%`, `echo`, etc.

Comment: @JimBalter we are in agreement

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
import json

var jsonResponse = %*
                   {"data": [{ "id": 35,
                               "type": "car",
                               "attributes": {"color":"red"} }]}

var body = ""

toUgly(body, jsonResponse)

echo body
```